# MySQL 5.6, how to export NULL as \N?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5, into-outfile, amazon-aurora

I am migrating a MySQL 5.5 physical host database to a MySQL 5.6 AWS Aurora database.  I noticed that when data is written to a file using `INTO OUTFILE`, 5.5 writes `NULL` value as `'\N'` and empty string as `''`.  However, 5.6 writes both empty string and NULL as  `''`.

Query

`SELECT * FROM $databasename.$tablename INTO OUTFILE $filename CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\\\' TERMINATED BY $delimiter;`

I found official documents about this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

> With fixed-row format (which is used when FIELDS TERMINATED BY and
>   FIELDS ENCLOSED BY are both empty), NULL is written as an empty
>   string. This causes both NULL values and empty strings in the table to
>   be indistinguishable when written to the file because both are written
>   as empty strings. If you need to be able to tell the two apart when
>   reading the file back in, you should not use fixed-row format.

How do I export `NULL` as `'\N'`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `\N` for `null` (without the `''`)? That would be the default behaviour for both 5.5 and 5.6, and for the case in your quote from the documentation, it will be empty for both 5.5 and 5.6 too. Did you by any chance use a different `$delimiter`? If it is empty, it will produce "nothing" for both `null` and `''`, just as the quote says. Did you get `'\N'` in the file, or in your database after your reimported it (and maybe reexported it again) - then you might have imported it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I export `NULL` as `'\N'`?

First of all that's strange and why you want to do that? But if for some reason you want to export it that way then you will have to change your query from `select *` to using a `CASE` expression like

```
select 
case when col1 is null then '\\N' else col1 end as col1,
...
from $databasename.$tablename....
```

As commented you can as well use `IFNULL()`  function or `COALESCE()` function for the same purpose.

Comment: case when col1 is null then '\N' else col1 end as col1 === ifnull(col1, '\N') AS col1

Comment: I suspect OP wants to return two characters,,, a backslash character and an N, and not a single newline character. To return a string containing a backslash and an N...  string literal would need to be:  `'\\N'`

Comment: @SIDU, that's right indeed. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: @spencer7593 Correct

Comment: @Rahul I want to export `NULL` as `'\N'` because I do not want to break any dependencies on the data from 5.5.  Also conceptually it makes sense to me: `NULL` and empty string are not the same, so why should they be exported as the same?

Comment: @Rahul For your query, would I have to substitute my column name for `col1`?  What if I had many columns?  Also, regarding the official docs, I thought either specifying `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` or `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY` would fix my issue.  But I realized my original query already have `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, just in a different order.  So I'm a bit confused

Comment: @onepiece, yes you will have to substitute `col1` with your original column name and you will have to do the same for all the columns